# What does the constant 0.0039215689 represent?

Tags: c, floating-point, constants, magic-numbers

I keep seeing this constant pop up in various graphics header files

```
0.0039215689
```

It seems to have something to do with color maybe?

Here is the first [hit on Google](http://ozmav.googlecode.com/svn-history/r178/trunk/badrdp/rdp.c):

```
void RDP_G_SETFOGCOLOR(void)
{
    Gfx.FogColor.R = _SHIFTR(w1, 24, 8) * 0.0039215689f;
    Gfx.FogColor.G = _SHIFTR(w1, 16, 8) * 0.0039215689f;
    Gfx.FogColor.B = _SHIFTR(w1, 8, 8) * 0.0039215689f;
    Gfx.FogColor.A = _SHIFTR(w1, 0, 8) * 0.0039215689f;
}

void RDP_G_SETBLENDCOLOR(void)
{
    Gfx.BlendColor.R = _SHIFTR(w1, 24, 8) * 0.0039215689f;
    Gfx.BlendColor.G = _SHIFTR(w1, 16, 8) * 0.0039215689f;
    Gfx.BlendColor.B = _SHIFTR(w1, 8, 8) * 0.0039215689f;
    Gfx.BlendColor.A = _SHIFTR(w1, 0, 8) * 0.0039215689f;

    if(OpenGL.Ext_FragmentProgram && (System.Options & BRDP_COMBINER)) {
        glProgramEnvParameter4fARB(GL_FRAGMENT_PROGRAM_ARB, 2, Gfx.BlendColor.R, Gfx.BlendColor.G, Gfx.BlendColor.B, Gfx.BlendColor.A);
    }
}

//...more like this
```

What does this number represent? Why does no one seem to declare it as a const?

I couldn't find anything on Google that explained it.

Comment: Note: Color components (e.g. red, green, blue, alpha) are often represented as an integer in [0 ; 255] in many APIs

Comment: Is there any reason the source code would write this instead of `(1.f/255)` ?

Comment: @MattMcNabb Maybe they are hoping it will not be evaluated in extended precision.

Comment: Mmmm...if only there were some way to avoid magic numbers....

Comment: `1/255 == 0.00(3921568627450980)` -- parens mean repetition.

Comment: With your next magic number, [try asking Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0.0039215689)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Note, that in base-256, the expansion will clearly be `{00}.{01}{01}{01}{01}...` where `{01}` is the single digit "one" in base-256. So in binary it will be `0.(00000001)` where the parens mean repetition.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: in base-256, it is: `0.(1)` (`1` is a more traditional representation of "one" than `{01}`)

Comment: whatever the reason, using a magic number without documenting its purpose is very uncool

Comment: @LionC I don't agree with the latest edit on this question. While it can be argued that the question itself has nothing to do with `C`, it has very much to do with `floating-point`.

Comment: @crush Youre probably right, seems I brainfarted there ;-) thx

Comment: `C` dev have reflexes... optimizing at the place of the compiler. Why is it the first version? Have a problem, then solve it.

Comment: @IsaacRabinovitch, I'm afraid I have received complaints about overcommenting things in code.... there are tastes for everything... but I'm with you.

Comment: @LuisColorado, have you ever gotten a complaint for documenting a magic number?  That would be a first, but it wouldn't surprise me given the toxicity of the field...

Comment: @AakashM, there is also the [Inverse Symbol Calculator](https://wayback.cecm.sfu.ca/cgi-bin/isc/lookup?lookup_type=browse&page_no=0&number=.0039215689), but it is less useful in this case because of the rounding.

Comment: @SO_fix_the_vote_sorting_bug, I was asking only.  Does the constant respresent something?, then a `#define` would be nice, just to understand that it is not an error (or has some typo)  BTW it's used several times with the same value.  A typo can be fatal if you change the value from one line to the next.

Answer (score 387, accepted):

`0.0039215689` is approximately equal to `1/255`.

Seeing that this is OpenGL, performance is probably important. So it's probably safe to guess that this was done for performance reasons.

Multiplying by the reciprocal is faster than repeatedly dividing by 255.

---

**Side Note:**

If you're wondering why such a micro-optimization isn't left to the compiler, it's because it is an unsafe floating-point optimization. In other words:

```
x / 255  !=  x * (1. / 255)
```

due to floating-point round-off errors.

So while modern compilers may be smart enough to do this optimization, they are not allowed to do it unless you explicitly tell them to via a compiler flag.

**Related:** [Why doesn't GCC optimize a*a*a*a*a*a to (a*a*a)*(a*a*a)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6430448/922184)

Comment: Wow. All I can say is awesome answer. I probably would never have discovered this without your knowledge. Of course, now knowing what it represents, it seems quite obvious!

Comment: I actually didn't know what it was when I first saw it. But seeing the way it was used, I suspected it was the multiply-by-reciprocal optimization. So I checked in my calculator and sure enough - I guessed right.

Comment: Fascinating.  I suppose, on a modern processor, multiplication can be faster than a look-up table.  Then again, I'd expect a conversion from an 8-bit color channel to float would want a gamma correction (or even an sRGB to linear conversion), in which case a look-up table is probably a win.

Comment: I would've expected to see it written as `a = b * (1.0f / 255)`; compilers still do constant folding, don't they?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Yes, they still do constant folding. It's actually required for some stuff like template resolutions and such. But I would've just pulled it out as a constant or a macro. But hey, not all code is perfectly written. :)

Comment: strict floating point adherence... isn't that what the `strictfp` keyword is for (if you need it)?

Comment: @Bohemian IIRC, the standard allows some leeway in that intermediate results of a floating-point expression can be done at higher precision. `strictfp` turns that off. But to do unsafe floating-point optimizations that require associativity ([such as this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430448/why-doesnt-gcc-optimize-aaaaaa-to-aaaaaa)), you need to tell the compiler to do it. (In GCC, it would be `-ffast-math`.)

Comment: @Bohemian `strictfp` is not part of the C standard. It exists in Java but one should not mix discussions of Java and C with regard to floating-point, they are each complex enough on their own (and quite different).

Comment: It seems strange to me that such things would be using a scale of 255 rather than 256. Am I missing something?

Comment: @hippietrail Initially, I was wondering the same thing. But if you use 256, it would scale from `0.0 - 0.996` instead the desired `0.0 - 1.0`. (`0.996 = 255/256` where `255` is the largest 8-bit integer)

Comment: An interesting question could be - why not 0.0039215686 or 0.0039215687, which are closer approximations at the same level of precision?

Comment: And of course, to answer my own question, it's because the other two numbers can not be represented as standard C floats. The next float below 0.0039215689 is 0.0039215684.

Comment: To be precise, the closest IEEE single-precision floating-point number to 1/255 is 0.0039215688593685626983642578125.

Comment: Of course, a better programmer writing the header file would have defined a constant and used it by name.

Comment: @JackAidley That's the odd thing. I couldn't find a single example online where a programmer defined a constant, yet, this magic number seems to be in widespread use. I actually first encountered it while disassembling an executable that was written in C++. Since then, I've been unable to find a single instance where it's defined as a constant...it might be that it's part of some standard graphics library.

Comment: It's maybe worth pointing out that there is a similar trick for integers to multiply a reciprocal rather than divide using [magic numbers](http://www.hackersdelight.org/magic.htm).  For example n/255 = (0x80808081*n)>>39.

Comment: @Mysticial Wait...why is it faster to multiply by the reciprocal than divide by 255?

Comment: @RakshithRavi Because division is slower than multiplication.

Comment: @Mysticial yeah but why?

Comment: @RakshithRavi http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745819/why-is-division-more-expensive-than-multiplication

Answer (score 79):

This multiplication by `0.0039215689f` converts an integer valued color intensity in the range 0 to 255 to a real valued color intensity in the range 0 to 1.

As Ilmari Karonen points out, even if this is an optimisation it's a rather badly expressed one. It would be so much clearer to multiply by `(1.0f/255)`.

Comment: Or maybe better, defined as constant?

Comment: @Johny Certainly defined as a constant. The point being not a magic value.