# Efficiently multiplying with a constant fraction in C++

Tags: c++, performance

I am implementing a Runge–Kutta procedure, which includes several time-critical multiplications with fixed, complicated fractions (which are not magic numbers but inherent to the algorithm) and I want this multiplications to be performed as efficient as possible whilst keeping the code readable.

For simplicity’s sake, let’s assume my code would look like the following, if I did not need to care about efficiency:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    a[i] += f(i) + b[i] * (2197/4104.);
```

Can I assume that every reasonable compiler (with optimisation) will effectively replace 2197/4104 by 0.535331…? If not, what are good ways to ensure this? Would defining a `const double` suffice, for example?

(Note that I am not interested in other possibilities for optimisation of the above code – it’s really just an example.)

Comment: Yes. And if it doesn't for whatever reasons, just make a `const float` (or `const double`) that stores the value and use that instead.

Comment: Note: If you're already concerning such small optimizations, you have already profiled your program and found this to be the bottle neck, did you? Otherwise, don't bother. Compilers are usually smart enough.

Comment: @Zeta: It may not be the bottle neck but sufficiently relevant in some cases. Anyway, not only does my compiler have to be smart enough, but (almost) everybody’s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using any recent compiler, the evaluation will be done at compile time.

However, if you cannot guarantee that the compiler will, simply lift the calculation out of the loop (making a `const long double` if possible):

```
long double fraction = (2197/4104.);
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  a[i] += f(i) + b[i] * fraction;
```

If accuracy of summation is important and the size of `f(i)` or `b[i]` is potantially large (I assume it could be), you're better off not using `+=` to sum the values, instead look at the [Kahan summation algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm) to sum, with minimal loss of precision. Alternatively, try to work with integral types while summing and then performing the division as a final step.

Comment: Even though this used to be the norm, I do expect that modern compilers are able to perform this optimization automagically.

Comment: This _may_ actually degrade the performance. Not to say that it may produce different results.

Comment: Yes, I agree. However, the part in the question specifically asking `what is a good way to ensure this`. However, I take your point and have updated my answer.

Comment: It reminds me of a recent question about why OpenGL source files repeatedly use a literal constant for 1/255. Can't find it though.

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy that was a [great question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22621241/what-does-the-constant-0-0039215689-represent/22621361#22621361) easier to find if you remembered that [Mysticial](http://stackoverflow.com/users/922184/mysticial) provided the most excellent answer to that question.

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy: In what cases may this degrade the performance? If the compiler does not optimise it?

Comment: @rich.okelly: Why do you use `long double` instead of `const long double` in your example code?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft just in case those numbers aren't actually constant in the OPs code (I believe they've posted an equivalent snippet), I have however included in my answer that it should be a const if possible.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft, well, I think it was a far-fetched supposition on my part. In small code snippet like this it is unlikely that performance should degrade. Anyway, only profiling may give the ultimate answer.

Answer (score 0):

In order to skip the floating point arithmetics you always can multiply your numbers by 100000 (I just looked at the Runge-Kutta on wiki, that's from where the number is) and do the entire algorithm on integers and when you actually need the result divide again with 100000. You use 2197/4104 as 53533, and you calculate for the others (28561/56430 = 0.50435 -> 50435, etc ...) too.

Comment: Look up "Fixed Point Math".  A better denominator is one that is a power of 2 such as 65536.  This will allow right shifting which is a lot faster than division.