# How to convert rgb to hue color format?

Tags: python, colors, light, philips-hue

im working with the phue library and want to change the color with

```
b.set_group(group, "hue", color)
```

I have read, that color is a number between 0 and 65535.

I want to input a rgb number, so i will need to convert it first.
May someone got a idea how i can do this?

Comment: so do you want to convert it to the `color` or to `hue` ? Because `hue` is from range `[0, 1]` or `[0, 360]`

Comment: Please give example of the input format and the matching expected output

Comment: @Mahrkeenerh to the color please :)

Comment: well then you gotta figure out what the conversion is. 65535 doesn't sound like anything conventional

Comment: @mozway Input: r 100 g 100 b 100
Output should be the number from 0-65535 :)

Comment: can you check [Fastest formula to get Hue from RGB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23090019/fastest-formula-to-get-hue-from-rgb)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may gain some conversion help from these links:

https://github.com/PhilipsHue/PhilipsHueSDK-iOS-OSX/blob/00187a3db88dedd640f5ddfa8a474458dff4e1db/ApplicationDesignNotes/RGB%20to%20xy%20Color%20conversion.md

https://github.com/studioimaginaire/phue/blob/master/examples/rgb_colors.py