# How do I make a circular button?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

***I have this answers here : Correct with help of **Yossi**
[How to put buttons over UITableView which won't scroll with table in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14689805/how-to-put-buttons-over-uitableview-which-wont-scroll-with-table-in-ios)***

I know answers work with NavigationControllerController

**[self.navigationController.view addSubview:_btnCircle];**

I learned to write in Objective C iOS app. Please help me to implement to get the Circle button display on uitableview as shown below. Or help me search keywords.

Example 1:

[image]

Example 2:

[image]

Comment: Those are all custom Table Cells. Before worrying about circular buttons I would get my custom cell set up first. [You can find some inputs here](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/). About making buttons you already have got answers for that.

Comment: For everybody who is interested in adding a customizable UIButton on top of a UITableView, UICollectionView or a UIScrollView.

This solution may help http://stackoverflow.com/a/35622509/2269679

Answer (score 12):

The simplest way is to add QuartzCore Framework

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

and then use the following code for your button:

```
button.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * button.bounds.size.width;
```

Now you have the round button from the square one.

Comment: `width * 0.5` might be better to use.

Comment: Thank u, but how to show button on table view like example picture

Comment: You should add the button as a subview for your tableViewCell

Comment: And then you can use `[UITableViewCell viewWithTag:]` method to get the actual button and set the corner radius. Even better would be if you create a UITableViewCell subclass and do all you need in it's implementation. Then you can use IBOutlet properties and create a template XIB for the tableView.

Comment: @GoodSp33d: Why is `width * 0.5` better than `width / 2`? It's mathematically identical...

Comment: Divisions are slower. You might not gain significant advantage, but you know drops make an ocean ;)

Comment: @GoodSp33d good suggestion. [Why is division more expensive than multiplication?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745819/why-is-division-more-expensive-than-multiplication)

Comment: Bro how to button fixed, not scroll flow tableview

Comment: Thanks i have tips . goToTop = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
goToTop.frame = CGRectMake(130, 70, 60, 20);
[goToTop setTitle:@"go to top" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[goToTop addTarget:self action:@selector(goToTop) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[goToTop setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[goToTop.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]];
goToTop.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:13];
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:goToTop];

Answer (score 4):

In order to make any button round you need to set the cornerRadius property of the button.

Note- In order to make circle you need to make sure that height and width are equal and radius is set half of the width/height. This will make perfect round circle.

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btn setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 50)];
btn.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * btn.bounds.size.width;
```

Comment: Thank u, but how to show button on table view like example picture

Comment: you can create a new class inheriting from UITableViewCell Class. There you can create the button and add it.

Comment: get the refrence of button using tag and do like this uibutton *button==(uibutton*)[cell viewwithtag:urbutton tag];

Comment: Hi Thank i understand your mean, one more i want drag button, what method i can do?

Comment: @NovemberRain thats a different question. if you want to know than ask another question

Comment: Bro how to button fixed, not scroll flow tableview

Comment: I do it, but please help me Button Home fixed not scroll flowing tableview

http://i.stack.imgur.com/WIbjq.png

Answer (score 0):

For Swift:

```swift
button.layer.masksToBounds = true
button.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.width / 2
```

If you are creating a custom `UIButton` (or a custom `UIView`), implement the following inside the custom class:

```swift
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.width / 2
}
```